# Hide DIV without ID based on DIV style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can I hide DIV based on its style ?

I have this div which I need to hide:

```
<div style="font-family: helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: center; text-transform:     uppercase; font-size: 9px; letter-spacing: 2px; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px 0px 5px     !important; color: rgb(170, 170, 170) !important; clear: both;">...</div>
```

Can anyone give me an example please.

DIV is loading from another site so I don't have direct control to use "display:none".

Comment: "Can I hide DIV based on his style" what does mean this?

Comment: Are there any other unique elements around this element? A parent? Prior sibling, etc?

Comment: "Can I hide DIV based on his style" what does mean this?

Comment: Not sure, but if only thing for identifying this div is his style (which is very odd)... something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/W3DLy/

Answer (score 4):

You can use [CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to hide that div element base on the `style` attribute.

For instance:

```css
div[style^="font-family: helvetica"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Or look for a particular style:

```css
div[style*="color: rgb(170, 170, 170)"] {
    display: none;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/W3DLy/1/)**.

Answer (score 2):

```
var style = "font-family: helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: center; text-transform:     uppercase; font-size: 9px; letter-spacing: 2px; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px 0px 5px     !important; color: rgb(170, 170, 170) !important; clear: both;";
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)   {
    if(elems[i].getAttribute('style') == style) {
        elems[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Example: **http://jsfiddle.net/W3DLy/**

Answer (score 0):

This will filter/hide based off the letter-spacing attribute:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('letter-spacing') == '2px';
}).hide();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vb8sj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

select from the available divs based on

```
$('div').filter(function () {
    return $(this).css('font-size') == '9px';
}).css('display', 'none');
```

or some other aspect of the style that you think is unique to these divs, then set display style to none

Answer (score -2):

Just to hide the div you can use "display: none"

Comment: This DIV loads from another site. I can't modify it directly.

Comment: @Blazer: So you want to hide an advertisement or something that gets put into your page by your provider or a 3rd party script? That would most likely violate the terms of your agreement.

Comment: You could use Jquery and so something like 
$("div[text-align='center']:contains('...')").hide();

Comment: In the question, OP directly states that they cannot just directly use `display:none` - telling OP to just use `display:none` isn't useful at all in this case